# Why JSON not works when i put a single quotation on my input parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-ajax

i want to send data to server it works fine but today i found if my user put a single quotation on data entry it will not works and i trace by codes and understood the trace will not go to my action not at all and it do not gives me an error or somethings like this

my codes:

```
// this code will not works because has a single quotation on mydata parameter
var mydata="I'm a developer"; 

var inputParams = "{abc: '" + mydata + "'}";


 fra = $.ajax({
    url: "/Updateit",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: inputParams,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg) {
        ......
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        ......
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
var mydata = "I'm a developer";
inputParams = { abc: mydata };
$.ajax({
  ....
  data: JSON.stringify(inputParams),
  ...
```

Comment: Post your action method